# Illegal light ball in Principled Volume setting

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

I wanted to make a video with fog lights.
Therefore, I set the Principled Volume setting in the UV, shined a spotlight, and set the animation.
When render, an unintended ball of light will be displayed at a rate of about 1 in 10.
I think Principled Volume setting is causing the problem because it doesn't occur when the Principled Volume setting is unconfigured.
If anyone knows how to deal with it, please teach me.
The operating environment is Windows 10 blender ver 2.93.

Comment: The problem is you have singularities where light gets reflected on a single point or a very small area and light values are far exceeding 1.00, and the bloom algorithm goes haywire because of that. Try playing with the clamp in bloom settings (0 means no clamp) https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQywx.png

Answer (score 3):

Presumably this is Eevee?  It matters.

It's not that the light is visible; its that the fog is illuminated by the light, and the light falls off with the square of distance-- so at a distance of 0, the brightness of the fog is infinite.  Because the fog is sampled, at a fairly low resolution, some pixels will run through a very bright bit of fog sometimes but not other times.

There are a few things you can do here.  One is to improve the tile size and the number of samples for your volumetrics (in properties/render/volumetrics.)  Higher samples and a smaller tile size are better.  This will make different frames more similar to each other, because you'll get more samples, evening things out.  It will also reduce performance, and won't completely solve the issue, merely mitigate it.

Another is to clamp the volumetric lighting, which can be done in properties/render/volumetrics/volumetric lighting/light clamping.  This sets a maximum brightness for any particular volumetric sample; when it is set to 0, the default, it is unclamped.  You will probably want to use very high values here, well outside the 0,1 range (like 1000 for the image shown below, with default scale monkeys.)

A third option is to reduce the density of the volumetric near the light.  This can be done by modulating the density on the basis of the length of object coordinates measured from the offending light:

[image]

This image compares modulated density on the left with unmodulated density on the right.  I'm controlling my density such that it is 0 for fog within 0.5 units of the light, 0.2 for fog further than 3.0 units from the light, and interpolates linearly between those two distances.

Comment: solved!
Thank you!
I created it based on the result.
The next challenge is the shadow. Also, I would be grateful if you could teach me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMNcD6kM4og